# Cordova android app sqlite plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

Unable to change the default location of sqlite plugin

```
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
name: 'test.db',
location: "default"
```

});

Database is created but destroyed after uninstaling the app.I have used codova file plugin

```
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
    name: 'test.db',
    location: cordova.file.externalRootDirectory //Tried all cordova.file.* location
});
```

But still location is not changed

Comment: Now i m using cordova-sqlite-ext and able to use prepopulated db